# PHP 5.4 PSA-Horde and Plesk 12 - How do I configure Active Sync?

Tags: php, activesync

PHP 5.4  PSA-Horde and Plesk 12 - How do I configure Active Sync?
Ladies and gentlemen

after a lot of hours getting more and more depressiv I hope one of you could help me figure out why my active sync stuff is not working.

First of all this is my server setup:
- PHP 5.4
- Plesk 12
- PSA-Horde (horde from plesk)

I used this tutorial to active the active sync features http://www.stiftnet.de/activesync-mit-horde-einsetzen/ and also you can find a similar tutorial here: http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/plesk-11-5-horde-get-activesync.288533/

The problem is my rpc.php is not executed by php. It just shows the rpc.php source. :-/ When I try to configure my apache I have the problem that the PHP_FLAGS or deprecated in PHP 5.4.

How do I have to configure it?

I have to use Horde by Plesk. So installing via pear is no option I think.

Comment: What's the output of this command. apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

Comment: core_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 aclr_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 cloudflare_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)

Comment: dav_lock_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 jk_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 rpaf_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
Syntax OK

Comment: Obviously your apache does not support PHP. try this commands. 
a2enmod php5  then  apache2ctl restart

Comment: Thanks seems to work now! I should have looked for the Apache settings and runnings modules :( Thank you so much!

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing apache's php module support. 
try this commands

```
a2enmod php5
```

then

```
apache2ctl restart
```